# SSH into other machines on a local network that has a firewall?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, firewall

My internet service is included with my apartment rent. They have a firewall and the router is inaccessible to me. I'm trying to ssh from a macOS that is connected to a wifi into my other machines (Linux) that are connected to ethernet. It works fine when I use ethernet on both ends, but I can't figure out a way to ssh into my local devices when I'm connected to WiFi. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably client isolation on the WiFi... Common in your situation, although without access to the router there is no way to verify that definitively.

Comment: But how to solve it?

Comment: Without control of the router or WiFi network? You're not going to. Best bet is get your own Internet service. The answer below says get a separate router of your own connect it to the wired Ethernet, which will likely work internally, but you will be double NATing and you will never get remote access to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your WiFi devices are isolated from the devices connected via ethernet you could create your own network behind that router of your apartment. This had the advantage that you are able to control the configuration of the LAN.
A simple way to achieve this is would involve:

1. Buying a (wifi-) router. You can do this setup even with cheap home router.
2. Connect the WAN port of the router to any of the ethernet ports you may use in your apartment.
3. Move all devices to the ethernet and wifi interfaces of your new router.
4. Turn off the wifi isolation, if necessary.
5. Turn on NAT on the WAN port, this is usually enabled by default with most routers for private consumers.

The resulting network will then appear as one device to the upstream network due to (5).
In any case, make sure that such a usage is allowed with your contract.