# Issues SSHing into Raspberry Pi 5 device on local network using WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ethernet

I am trying to SSH into a Raspberry Pi 5 on my local network, connected via ethernet. I am using `ssh user@rpi5.local`, and this works when the machine I am SSHing from is also connected via ethernet, but not just WiFi.

I am still on the same network, just the Raspberry Pi 5 is connected with ethernet and the laptop with WiFi.

As soon as I connect the laptop to ethernet, SSH works fine. Both ping and SSH return the error saying that it cannot resolve the hostname:

> “rpi5.local: Name or service not known.”

It also fails when attempting to connect via IP address as well.

I am in an apartment and do not have access to the router. Is [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1641601/1892651) my only option?

Comment: No, fails with the IP address as well.

Comment: @kinneyan - That means your Ethernet and WiFi are not part of the same network, without the ability to change the configuration of the WiFi access point, there is little that can be done to make devices discoverable on another network